# How to add new column in dataframe with count if formula in R PROGRAMMING

Tags: r

This is my code: first column is 'Case id', 2nd column is 'message'. I want to add a new column in the data frame with a count of "Welcome" in the 'message' column.

```r
Case_id<-c("#1","#1","#1","#1","#1","#2","#2","#2","#2","#2")
message<-c("welcome to dell","welcome to dell","refresh your screen","connect to agent","Thanks good day","welcome to dell","select from default","refresh your screen","connect to agent","Thanks good day") 

df <- data.frame(Case_id, message)
    
sum(df$Case_id=="#1" & grepl("welcome*",df$message))
```

Expected output:

```r
    Case id   message             Welcome message repeated
    #1        "welcome to..."         2
    #1        "welcome to..."         2
    #1        ""refresh your...."     2
    #1        ""connect to agent"     2
    #1        "Thanks good day"       2
    #2        "Welcome to..."         1
    #2         ......                 1
    #2
    #2
    #2
```

Comment: I'm confuse here. Where is python involve here?

Comment: I have removed the `python` code tag. Please use code tags appropriately & only if they apply. On Stack Overflow, it's advisable to ask a question in one *specific*  language.

Comment: I don't understand your expected output. Why do you have a count of 2 for `"refresh your ..."`for case id = #1? I can only see a single row with `"refresh your screen"` for that ID.

Answer (score 0):

For each group (i.e., `Case_id`), we can get a count of how many times 'welcome' occurs in the group.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(Case_id) %>%
  mutate("Welcome message repeated" = sum(str_detect(message, "welcome*")))
```

Or in base R:

```
transform(df, "Welcome message repeated" = ave(+(grepl("welcome*", message)), Case_id, FUN = sum))
```

**Output**

```
   Case_id message             `Welcome message repeated`
   <chr>   <chr>                                    <int>
 1 #1      welcome to dell                              2
 2 #1      welcome to dell                              2
 3 #1      refresh your screen                          2
 4 #1      connect to agent                             2
 5 #1      Thanks good day                              2
 6 #2      welcome to dell                              1
 7 #2      select from default                          1
 8 #2      refresh your screen                          1
 9 #2      connect to agent                             1
10 #2      Thanks good day                              1
```

Another option is that you can use `summarise` to get the summary count for each group.

```
df %>%
  group_by(Case_id) %>%
  summarise("Welcome message repeated" = sum(str_detect(message, "welcome*")))

#  Case_id `Welcome message repeated`
#  <chr>                        <int>
#1 #1                               2
#2 #2                               1
```